# Is there a way to convert the current time / timezone with Apple Script?

Tags: time, timezone, applescript

I have a basic Apple Script that will return the current time based on the users timezone, however, I would like to expand this to where it will add or subtract hours to adjust to other timezones. For example, If it's 2:29:15 PM CDT, I would like to create a script that will subtract two hours from that to reflect the current time in the Pacific timezone (12:29:15 PM PDT). I would most likely make separate scripts that add or subtract a certain number of hours, so I don't need for this script to handle every timezone.

Here is what I have so far:

`set t to (time string of (current date))`

Comment: AppleScript doesn’t have any built-in capabilities for working with timezones beyond `time to GMT`. You’ll have to get down and dirty with Cocoa’s `NSDate` and related classes via the AppleScript-ObjC bridge. I did write a [`Date` library](https://github.com/hhas/applescript-stdlib) way back when that wrapped some of that, although ISTR it wasn’t passing all of its unit tests when I parked it, so caveat emptor. (I’m not sure if that was due to bugs in the library or bugs in the tests—dates are a nightmare to do right, particularly over long spans of historical time.)

Comment: @foo Surely `time to GMT` and a list of (abbreviation-GMT offset) pairs is all one needs, though.  [**List of UTC time offsets**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets)

Comment: And what happens if you run the script when the clocks are changing? Dates, Unicode, XML, crypto… there’s always some corner case behaviors a naive homegrown solution overlooks. Just use the existing system APIs; it’s what they’re there for.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but if you just want to shift the time of a date by a few hours, you can use a handler like so:

```
on shiftTimeZone(givenDate, hoursDifference)
    return givenDate + (hoursDifference * hours)
end shiftTimeZone

set curd to (current date)
log time string of curd
(*e.g. 6:56:59 PM*)
set newd to shiftTimeZone(curd, -3)
log time string of newd
(*e.g. 3:56:59 PM*)
```